# Postgres database sync missing left sibling

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm currently trying to compare/sync two databases, sync the changes from the test DB to the live DB. Both are running Postgres 9.1 and the test DB was a dump of the live one.

When I try a compare/sync with a program like "Navicat" or "SQL Management Studio", I get the error:

> Error: ERROR:  could not find left sibling of block 176 in index
>   "pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index"

I searched and googled, but I don't really understand what the problem is.
Also when I make the DB select in both databases:

```
SELECT * from pg_attributes
```

It doesn't show any problem. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you do full vacuum on the command line and see what happens? `VACUUMDB -a -f -z <other-connection-params>`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, DrColossos. I made a vacuum on the whole DB, which worked, but I get still the same error. Also a restart didn't helped.